# Difference between useRef and callbackRef (React Hooks)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I read React's documentation and they mentioned:

> If you want to run some code when React attaches or detaches a ref to
>   a DOM node, you may want to use a callback ref instead.
>
> In order to measure the position or size of a DOM node, you can use a
>   callback ref.

But, I still don't understand the difference between using useRef and callbackRef, does anyone can offer a better explanation?

For example, if useRef and callbackRef are different why the following two codes have the same result?

useRef:

```
  const h1Ref = React.useRef(null)
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setHeight(h1Ref.current.getBoundingClientRect().height);
  },[])
```

Callback ref:

```
 const measuredRef = useCallback(node => {
    if (node !== null) {
      setHeight(node.getBoundingClientRect().height);
    }
  }, []);
```

Here is a sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/use-refvscallbackref-djjgg

Comment: `useCallback` returns memoized function reference to you, in your example you are storing that in `measuredRef` but in your code you are not doing anything with it, so what makes you think both are doing the same thing?